# PyMC and arviz problem when trying to get summary statistics

Tags: bayesian, pymc, arviz

I am building a Bayesian Regression model (see the code bellow) using the PyMC library. When trying to get summary statistics, trace plot and posterior plot I get an error.

I am using Google Colab. Here is the version I am using of PyMC and arviz:
Name: pymc
Version: 5.7.2
Name: arviz
Version: 0.15.1

Code:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    #priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=global_mean_performance, sigma=global_std_performance)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sigma=10)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sigma=10)

    #expected value of outcome
    mu = alpha + beta * X

    #likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed=Y)
  
    #model fitting
    trace = pm.sample(100, return_inferencedata=False)
```

Error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 summary = az.summary(trace)
2 print(summary)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/arviz/data/converters.py in convert_to_inference_data(obj, group, coords, dims, **kwargs)
128             "cmdstanpy fit",
129         )
--> 130         raise ValueError(
131             f'Can only convert {", ".join(allowable_types)} to InferenceData, '
132             f"not {obj.**class**.**name**}"

ValueError: Can only convert xarray dataarray, xarray dataset, dict, netcdf filename, numpy array, pystan fit, emcee fit, pyro mcmc fit, numpyro mcmc fit, cmdstan fit csv filename, cmdstanpy fit to InferenceData, not MultiTrace

I have tried to find post with similar problem, but I haven't found the correction solution